# AngularJS change/transaction log for arrays

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have the following scenario. I would like to bind a list of objects to a HTML table and make use of angularJS's two way data binding. Nothing fancy, pretty basic scenario.

I have two questions:

1. If i am watching the model for changes -  which is an array of objects - why doesn't Angular give me the actual list of changes? I am not comparing by reference, and i don't want to have the old value and the new value, because that's of no use to me. I need the actual changed "cells". If Angular is doing dirty checking via some kind of diffing, it can give me those changes anyway, there is no need for me to do extra diffing of those arrays - imagine they are 1000-2000 entries, and each object has at least 10 props.
2. Haven't measured the performance myself, and wanted to ask you before i do it: What do you think is better, watching the whole model and diff it, row by row, cell by cell, vs. watching every object (data row) in the array separately, and then diffing prop by prop?

In any way, i think $digest should return some kind of transaction log, which gives me the prev/new values, as well as the index (or key?) of the object where the change occured.

Btw, i was also wondering, does angular support the notion of keys, such as primary keys? Does it associate a changed object in the array by its index only?

Answer (score 0):

I've forked Angular and implemented it for 2D arrays:

https://github.com/attodorov/angular.js

The changes and the reason behind them are described here:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/angel_todorov/archive/2013/06/17/hacking-angularjs.aspx